Old outlet, not controlled by switch, has 4 screws, 6 wires, top screws 1 white wire, 1 black wire, Bottom screws each- 2 white and 2 black
Old outlet not controlled by switch, 6 wires- 3 white, 3 black, top screws 1 white on left, 1 black on right, bottom screws- 2 white on left bottom, 2 black on right bottom, how do I change to new outlet with 4 screws Help Please

Check the old outlet.  Is there a small metal brass colour tab/piece of metal connecting the two screws on each side?  Be care if there is not since the outlet might be controlled by two breakers.  Turning only one breaker off leaves power to half of the outlet.  If tabs are still there, then connect the two blacks as in your switch question.
